# pcl ExtractIndices nodelet

Tags: pcl-conversions, message-filters, nodelet, pointcloud, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the [perception_pcl](http://wiki.ros.org/perception_pcl) nodelets. I have a point cloud being fed to a SACSegmentation nodelet. That nodelet works fine and I am able to see the output at the expected 30Hz.

However, when I feed the inliers from the segmenter and the original point cloud into a pcl/ExtractIndices nodelet, I get no output, or perhaps one frame randomly every 1 - 2 minutes.

This appears to be caused by some recent update as it has worked before and still works on another, unupdated computer. Has there been a change of this node or the way to use it or should I file a ticket?

**EDIT:**
I dug a little deeper and found out the cause of my problem.  The extractIndices filter uses a Synchronize message filter with an exact timestamp policy to match the input point cloud and the indices found by the segmenter.  The segmenter is NOT producing an inlier message with the same timestamp as the original pointcloud on my updated computers. Therefore, the extractIndices callback never gets called. The original point cloud has a stamp that is more precise than the indices.

For example, the pointcloud will have a stamp of

```
secs: 1438114448
nsecs: 434060100
```

while the indices will have

```
secs: 1438114448
nsecs: 434060000
```

So the segmentation nodelet loses precision when it reads the input point cloud. Not so in my unchanged computer. I noticed the segmenter uses a pointcloud rather than a pointcloud2, but I still can't find the place where things changed to cause my error.  Anybody know where the change was?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212962/pcl-extractindices-nodelet/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue and setting the approximate_sync param to true fixed it for me:

```
<!-- Extract Inlier points -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="extract_plane" args="load pcl/ExtractIndices pcl_manager" output="screen">
  <remap from="~input" to="/voxel_grid/output"/>
  <remap from="~indices" to="/sac_plane/inliers"/>
  <rosparam>
    negative: true
    approximate_sync: true
</rosparam>
</node>
```

Hope this helps you too!

---

Originally posted by [MahdiehNejati](https://answers.ros.org/users/24953/mahdiehnejati/) with karma: 86 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4